# Are xlab ylab and zlab in persp() incompatible with bquote?

Tags: r, plot

I wondering how can I use `bquote` in the **xlab, ylab** and **zlab** in `persp()` in R. Specifically, I'm trying to put Greek letters `mu` for **xlab**, `sigma` for **ylab** and "`Likelihood~(mu, sigma)`" for **zlab** ithout success? (any alternatives to allow using Greek letters?)

**Here is my R code:**

```
x = seq(-10, 10, len = 30)

y = seq(0, 5, len = 30)

f = function(x, y) { dnorm(2, x, y) }

z <- outer(x, y, f)


persp(x, y, z , theta = 30, phi = 30, expand = 0.5, col = 'lightblue',
  xlab = bquote(mu), ylab = bquote(sigma), zlab = bquote('Likelihood'~(mu)~"," ~ (sigma)) )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`persp` does not allow expressions. Try using unicode symbols instead

```
persp(x, y, z , theta = 30, phi = 30, expand = 0.5, col = 'lightblue',
      xlab = "\u03bc",
      ylab = "\u03c3",
      zlab = paste('Likelihood ',"\u03bc", "\u03c3", sep = "") )
```